# How to fetch copied to clipboard content in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

How to get the 'clipboard' content in cypress. I have a button in my web application, on click of button  system will perform 'copy to clipboard' and a message will get displayed. Below is an example of the url content that is copy to clipboard ( *this url content is different from web site url*)

https://someurl.net/machines/0c459829-a5b1-4d4b-b3c3-18b03c1c969a/attachments/a30ceca7-198e-4d87-a550-04c97fbb9231/download

I have double check that there is no `href` attribute in that button tag. So I have use a plugin called clipboardy and I have added `plugins/index.js` file

```
 const clipboardy = require('clipboardy');
    module.exports = ( on ) => {
        on('task', {
            getClipboard () {
                return clipboardy.readSync();
            }
        });
    };
```

In my test I have used cy.task() to get the clipboard content, but this is not printing the actual url content

```
cy.get('td').find('div').find('span').find('button').find('i').eq(0).click().then(()=>{
          cy.task('getClipboard').then((data)=>{
          console.log("Helloooo:"+data);
      })
    })
```

```html
<td class="sc-hgRTRy duUdhJ">
<div>
<span class="sc-bYwvMP jTmLTC">
<span class="sc-jzJRlG iVpVVy">
<span role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="5aa03785-1370-455e-a838-4154f7481a7b">
<button class="sc-feJyhm cJOKrG">
<i class="icon fas fa-link sc-htpNat cQABgO" aria-hidden="true" data-component-type="icon">
</i>
</button>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried `getClipboard () {
            return clipboardy.read();
        }` as well

Comment: The test given by @MakwanaPrahlad (using an input) works, so that suggests that your button `.click()` is not triggering the event. That may be the 'native events' problem, but it's also possible the click is not on the right element. Can you show part of the html that has the `td`?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know if the 'copy to clipboard' message appears when running the test.

Comment: Yes it is displaying the message while running the text. I totally agree to @MakwanaPrahlad test, but my case is different though

Comment: I will add the html..

Comment: Added the <td> html tag

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think the point about @MakwanaPrahlad's test is that it proves your approach to checking the clipboard content is valid. It also means that there's nothing in the clipboard within your `.then()`. You could try a `wait()` before the `cy.task()`, in case the copy-to-clipboard process is slow (your test will run clipboardy ms after the click).

Comment: I have tried waiting for 5 seconds. But still not good. I have also confirmed if the clipboard content is still available by manually press Ctrl V after the message in a new tab in the cypress browser and paste it there..I could see content there..

Comment: OK. What does `console.log(data)` look like? Undefined, or a jquery object?

Comment: It just print the whole cy.task() function..

Comment: I don't understand, can you post it on the question? Normally the parameter of `.then()` is a jquery object, so you probably can't do `"Hello:" + data`, instead maybe `"Hello:" + data[0]`.

Comment: @soccerway I am currently facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve this? I think the index.js file is run before the tests and then whatever content the clipboard had before it will just use that and not the latest content.

Comment: @AlapanDas Sorry it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to use [clipboardy package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboardy) you can also use this:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
      expect(text).to.eq('your copied text');
    });
  });
```

in your case, it turns to something like

```
   cy.get('td').find('div').find('span').find('button').find('i').eq(0).click().then(()=>{
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
        console.log("Helloooo:"+text);
      });
    });
   })
```

Comment: I keep getting the exception "Document is not focused"

Comment: Make sure that you haven't clicked away to another window or something. I've gotten the same error, and it was literally just that the browser that is being tested had to be the active window.

Comment: What syntax do you use to check for text value within then() ? expect( ) what ?

Comment: Putting this out there for visibility, but this snippet will not fail a test suite if the `expect` assertion fails, which defeats the purpose of testing the clipboard. This example works for me: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__clipboard/cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js#L17-L19

Answer (score 8):

Accessing clipboard can be worked around, but the main issue is that the document.execCommand('copy') doesn't work (as stated above), which I reckon is the primary (and only?) way for your app to programmatically put a text to user's clipboard.

Assuming it happens somehow (or is fixed upstream), the checking the clipboard's contents can be done e.g. by using clipboardy:

`npm i -D clipboardy`

plugins/index.js:

```
const clipboardy = require('clipboardy');
module.exports = ( on ) => {
    on('task', {
        getClipboard () {
            return clipboardy.readSync();
        }
    });
};
```

In your specification:

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        cy.document().then( doc => {
            doc.body.innerHTML = '<input id="inp">';
        });
        cy.get('#inp').type('test{selectall}');
        cy.document().then( doc => {
            doc.execCommand('copy');
        });
        cy.task('getClipboard').should('contain', 'test');
    });
});
```

I hope this code will be usefull for you.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I have see the same approach earlier, in your example you have an input field, typing some text into that input field and then asserting that text content. My requirement is different, there is no input field in my web application, all I have is a button, when i click on the above button, some text content is copied into clipboard, then i will get a pop up message "Copied to Clipboard", I need to grab that clipboard content ( see my question above). I need to grab that url to proceed further with rest of business cases.

Comment: I have inspected and find there is no `href` attribute in that button ( as given in above screen shot in question )

Comment: I have tried the below one too, but it just print the code, `cy.get('td').find('div').find('span').find('button').find('i').eq(0).click().task('getClipboard').then((data)=>{
      console.log("Helloooo:"+data);
 })`

Comment: The readme page on github for clipboardy says that readSync() doesn't work in browsers. I'm also seeing intermittent issues where it causes the cypress test run to hang. Are other folks not seeing these issues?

Answer (score 8):

I have found this nice and simple solution of testing the clipboard content in Gleb Bahmutov's video [Access the clipboard from Cypress test using Electron browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SExmed1dCL4).

```
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
  .invoke('readText').should('equal', 'copied text')
```

---

It uses the new [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) (Chrome, FF and Opera: 2018; Safari and Edge: 2020; IE: no)

In the video, Gleb also suggets to test a case for browsers not supporting the Clipboard API, using an old (and deprecated) method of `document.execCommand('copy')`.

It expects the page to have an input field or textarea to paste the content. Let's assume it's `textarea#paste-here`.

```
// delete navigator.clipboard to force the app to use execCommand
cy.visit('index.html', {
  onBeforeLoad(window) {
    delete window.navigator.__proto__.clipboard
  }
})
cy.document().then(document => cy.spy(document, 'execCommand').as('exec'))

/* trigger the copy action here... cy.get(...).click() */

cy.get('@exec').should('have.been.calledOnceWith', 'copy')

cy.get('#paste-here').focus()
cy.document().invoke('execCommand', 'paste')

cy.get('#paste-here').should('have.value', 'copied text')
```

---

Due to the clipboard permissions dialog, this test can be automated (CI) only in Electron browser. To make it running in Chrome, take a look at another Gleb's video [Give Chrome Browser Clipboard Permissions from Cypress Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eEc3x24D64). Otherwise, you can limit the test to be run only in Electron using [Test configuration object](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Test-Configuration):

```
describe('Clipboard', {browser: 'electron'}, () => {
...
```

Comment: Interesting, my specs are "skipped due to browser" when electron is set

Comment: Also, cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
  .invoke('readText').should('equal', 'copied text') throws "TypeError": Cannot set property message of [object DOMException] which has only a getter  all of a sudden now ..

Comment: @trainoasis I get the same error you called out. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @mellis481 yeah, I used this after enabling browser access to clipboard via Cypress.automation("remote:debugger:protocol" ..) to make sure permissions were granted first:
    cy.window()
      .its("navigator.permissions")
      .then((api) => api.query({ name: "clipboard-read" }))
      .its("state")
      .should("equal", "granted");

Answer (score 5):

Late but if anyone is getting "Document is not focused" error from @marzzy's answer:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
      expect(text).to.eq('your copied text');
    });
  });
```

It's either because:

1. [You are executing code from the devtools console or snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61216014/8602886)
2. Or if you're using Chrome you have to give it clipboard permission like this:

```
cy.wrap(
    Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
        command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
        params: {
          permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
          origin: window.location.origin,
        },
    }),
);
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eEc3x24D64

Comment: Confirmed to work on cypress 10+ using Chrome 112.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the copied link by printing out the yielded value after clicking the button and then searched the object in the console in order to find the link. I found the link in  `[object]._vClipboard.clipboardAction.text`, as you can see below:

```
cy.get('[data-test=copy-link-button]').click().then(($clipboard) => {
   const copiedLink = $clipboard[0]._vClipboard.clipboardAction.text;
   cy.visit(copiedLink);
});
```

I hope that this will help.

Comment: How did you print out the yielded value?  My button has text of "Copy Text", so i can't grab it's own text, i need to grab what it is placing in the clipboard. So, i'm wondering how did you print the yielded value after clicking the button?

Comment: @SaintAvalon, you can do this:
`cy.get('[data-test=copy-link-button]').click().then(($value) => {
   console.log($value);
});` 
This will print to the console the yielded value after clicking the button. Then you can see the clipboard text in the object printed out in the console: `$value[0]._vClipboard.clipboardAction.text`.
Make sure you replace `[data-test=copy-link-button]` with your respective button's data-test

Answer (score 1):

Reading this really helped me solve my own issue, I had to use a mixture from the OP and the first comment.  This is what worked for me:

```
     cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .mat-card > .row > .col-sm-3 > .mat-focus-indicator').click().then(() => {
        cy.task('getClipboard').then(($clip) => {
             const url = $clip;
             cy.log('this is what was in clipboard', url);
             cy.visit(url);
         });
     });
```

This gave me the URL i wanted from the button I clicked.  I then just passed that right into cy.visit to visit the url i just copied.  Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

For me, none of the answers helped me taking de data from the clipboard. The next code worked:

First we will allow the access to the clipboard:

```
cy.window().its('navigator.permissions')
                .invoke('query', { name: 'clipboard-read' })
                .its('state').then(cy.log)
```

Then we access the clipboard

```
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
                .invoke('readText')
                .then((text) => {
                    cy.log(text)
                })
```

Hope this works for anyone here

Answer (score 0):

Code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653634/2742007 should be adapted to call **clipboardy** functions supported by browsers, as commented by "opike": mind the `async` and `read()` instead of `readSync()`.

```
const clipboardy = require('clipboardy');
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    async getClipboard() {
      return clipboardy.read();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Above usage of window.navigator https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871590/5667941 , only works for Electron. For Chrome user permisson would be required

[image: User permission request]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cy.window()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window) and you can use the [navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) as normal for pasting and copying.

```
it("Paste cliboard numbers", () => {
  cy.window()
    .then((win) => {
      return win.navigator.clipboard.writeText("234");
    `})`
    .then(() => {
      cy.get("[data-test=paste]").click();
      cy.get("[data-test=calc-input]").should("have.text", 234);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answares worked for me so far with the cypress ui but I managedto find a solution without any additional libs or plugins by using the Cypress.Promises and the window.navigator directly ... and here it is:

```
cy.window().then(win =>
  new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    win.navigator
      .clipboard
      .readText()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject))
).should('eq', '`myExpectedClipboardValue')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give clipboard read permission.Befor click button to have copied text add this.

```
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation("remote:debugger:protocol", {
command: "Browser.grantPermissions",
params: {
    permissions: ["clipboardReadWrite", "clipboardSanitizedWrite"],
    // make the permission tighter by allowing the current origin only
    origin: window.location.origin
}
```

}));