# How can I verify copied contents of my clipboard in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, clipboard, navigator

When I click a button:

```
cy.contains('Copy Token').click()
```

I want to automate verification that a specific set of text was copied. And before you ask: the `Copy Token` button works and always shares the same Token every time, so I know its not a problem with the website itself.

I am using a Cypress Project with Javascript.

### SOLUTION ATTEMPT #1:

I found this article: [Testing copy to clipboard with Cypress](https://dev.to/walmyrlimaesilv/testing-copy-to-clipboard-with-cypress-1414)

So I went ahead and tried converting this solution to my code:

```
it('should verify that the correct token was copied', () => {
...
token = '<almost 1900 character token>'
cy.contains('Copy Token').click()
cy.assertValueCopiedToClipboard(token)
} 

Cypress.Commands.add('assertValueCopiedToClipboard', value => {
  cy.window().then(win => {
    win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
      expect(text).to.eq(value)
    })
  })
})
```

This code does no verification. It's as if Cypress skips trying to verify what's been copied to the Clipboard, and I don't know why. It doesn't matter what I set `token` to.

### SOLUTION ATTEMPT #2:

This was a suggestion in a [StackOverflow Solution Comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871590/19657086), linking to [this GitHub link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__clipboard/cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js#L17-L19). So I tried this:

```
cy.contains('Copy Token').click()
var token = '1234567890'
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
    .then((clip) => clip.readText())
    .should('equal', token)
```

(The Token is a lot longer then that, this is just an example)

I will receive the error about 50/50:

```
-then function(){}

NotAllowedError
Document is not focused.
```

[According to Cypress's official page](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/focus), `.focus()` should be on the end of the command. So I've tried this (since I'm not supposed to focus on `cy.window`, right?)

```
cy.contains('Copy Token').click().focus()
var token = '<My-Token>'
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
    .then((clip) => clip.readText())
    .should('equal', token)
```

Still the same error. I feel like the 2nd Solution might be on the right track though, since I see the following in the output before the error:

```
its  navigator.clipboard
```

Anyways, at least the `Document is not focused` doesn't always come up, and when I don't receive this error, I will get the following error:

```
 ! AssertionError
 expected '<last-copied-item>' to equal '1234567890'
```

Where `<last-copied-item>` is the last set of text that I manually copied before running the test. So it looks like Cypress is able to access the Clipboard, but isn't properly copying the Token from `cy.contains('Copy Token').click()` (manually, I can tell you that this button works). Perhaps there is a permissions issue with Cypress?

I've also tried a couple other things, but they've resulted in Syntax Errors and I really don't think any of them are on the right track at all.

### Suggested Solution?

What should I do? Am I at least on the right track?