# Copy JSON to clipboard in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, clipboard

Is it possible to copy data to the clipboard in JSON format?
I tried to use [clipboardy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboardy), but it seems to not support it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778539/copy-to-clipboard-in-node-js