# How to copy multiple values into clipboard in node js?

Tags: node.js, clipboard

Title meaning, I have several strings, which I want to be in clipboard, like it would be if I copied them manually. Which also means, if I were to use default Windows Win+V command or Clipdiary - all of strings would appear as different values, as such:

[Manual copy = different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duodc.png)

But if you:

[Copy via code = they are replacing themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUtp3.png)

P.S. Screenshots of different ways (Clipdiary vs Win+V) to access clipboard were by choice, to show that its not the program fault or Windows.

It doesnt matter, but heres code from pictures, using [copy-paste](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-paste):

```js
const ncp = require(`copy-paste`);

ncp.copy(`But they`);
ncp.copy(`replace one another.`);
```

So, also I already tried [Clipboardy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboardy) v2.3.0 for CJS compatability and spawning child process from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39170919) to similar question - all the same:

```js
const cp = require('child_process').spawn('clip');

cp.stdin.write(`yo`);
cp.stdin.write(`hey`);

// and 

cp.stdin.write(`yo`);
cp.stdin.end(`hey`);

// and even spawning new processes

const cp2 = require('child_process').spawn('clip');
cp2.stdin.write(`hey`);
cp2.stdin.end(`yo`);

// and all other possible ways
```

And all other answers on that question also didnt worked for me. So, here I am questioning my sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked ChatGPT and got my answer:

```js
const copyPaste = require('copy-paste');

const valuesToCopy = [
  'Value 1',
  'Value 2',
  'Value 3',
  // Add more values as needed
];

async function copyValuesToClipboard() {
  for (const value of valuesToCopy) {
    copyPaste.copy(value, () => {
      console.log(`Copied: ${value}`);
    });
    await sleep(1000); // Delay for 1 second (adjust as needed)
  }
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

copyValuesToClipboard()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('All values copied to clipboard.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error copying values to clipboard:', err);
  });
```